# Microsoft Access Driver: Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 1114

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a .mdb database using the pyodbc module with the following code:

```
import pyodbc

MDB = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OnCourt\\OnCourt.mdb'
DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}'
PWD = 'qKbE8lWacmYQsZ2'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};DBQ={};PWD={}'.format(DRV,MDB,PWD))
```

This normally works absolutely fine but stopped working today, and I can't think why. This is the error I get:

InterfaceError: ('IM003', '[IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb), C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX64\Microsoft Shared\Office16\ACEODBC.DLL). (160) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I don't think it's anything specific to the database I'm trying to access as when I try to configure the driver from within ODBC data sources, I get essentially the same error there too:

[image]

Comment: I've just had the same problem. My code was working fine up until today, too. I wonder if a Windows Update was involved?

Comment: I tried rolling back the Windows updates from earlier this week but this didn't changed anything for me. At a complete loss what to do...very close to going down the nuclear restore factory settings route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same problem! I fixed it by uninstalling the driver and reinstalling it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920.

When I tried to re-install the first time, it whined that "You cannot install the 32-bit version of access because you currently have 64-bit Office products installed" and asked me to uninstall Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component 64-bit registration. So I followed the directions [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e118d02-5d3c-488a-953c-db4801becef6/office-16-clicktorun-extensibility-component-64bit-registration-prevents-access-2016-32bit) to uninstall that, then installed the driver. My program worked again!

No idea why that worked. Maybe an update screwed it up somehow? Who knows. Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks! worked for me too, but be sure to uninstall the driver first, that was a headache to me.

Answer (score 3):

Even easier fix.  Settings -> Add/Remove Programs-> Select "Microsoft Access database engine" and select Modify.

Brings up the installer, and select reinstall.

Works for me :).

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same issue.

Apps using ODBC which have worked for many years suddenly stopped working.  When running DEBUG in VS 2015, was showing up as "Loader Lock" exception.  If Managed Exception handler was disabled, it still refused to run, showing only a message box saying "The operating system is not configured to run this application".  Apps had to be killed via Task Manager.

Got that same thing when using \Windows\SysWow64\odbcad32.exe to "look at" the ODBC drivers installed.

I did exactly the same thing; MS Access Database Engine --> Modify --> Reinstall --> Reinstall

Problem solved.

I suppose it will come back the next time Office is "updated" ...?  Gee thanks, Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

ACEODBC.dll seems busted:

I found in my registry:

REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)]
"Driver"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\Office16\ACEODBC.DLL"
"Setup"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\Office16\ACEODBC.DLL"

I reverted the following 2 registry entries back to older JET version: (this is not a great solution but was the only one that fixed the problem for me).

REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)]
"Setup"=hex(2):25,57,49,4e,44,49,52,25,5c,73,79,73,74,65,6d,33,32,5c,6f,64,62,
63,6a,74,33,32,2e,64,6c,6c,00
"Driver"=hex(2):25,57,49,4e,44,49,52,25,5c,73,79,73,74,65,6d,33,32,5c,6f,64,62,
63,6a,74,33,32,2e,64,6c,6c,00

which is basically back to '%WINDIR%\system32\odbcjt32.dll'

My symptom was and ODBC execute on a 'REPAIR_DB' statement. The SQL call would completely hang program

Comment: Please correct the formatting of answer for better readability.